# Database schema with sails.js and sails-postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

Is there any way to set database schema with sails-postgresql waterline adapter?

By default postgres adapter allways choose default public schema in database but I want to connect it to another schema.

For example I have database dev, schema test in database dev and table users in schema test.
Now I want to select all data from table users, in sql syntax I can simply write:

```
SELECT * FROM test.users
```

How to make it work in sails ?

When I write a model that uses postgres adapter, method Users.find() will look for the table users in default public schema. I want to change it to look in schema test without interactions with my postgres database.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is support for this, although it is as-yet undocumented.  You can set the schema name for a model using the `meta.schemaName` property, eg:

```
module.exports = {

  tableName: 'users',
  meta: {
     schemaName: 'test'
  },

  attributes: {
     ...
  }

};
```

### Update

It turns out this functionality was essentially broken for several versions, but it has been revamped and released in Sails-Postgresql v0.11.0.  The syntax is the same as above.  The main caveat is that it will *not* work with multiple Waterline models sharing the same `tableName`.

Comment: Did this work for you? It still writes to public schema, regardless of the schemaName set to the model. Am I missing anything?

Comment: check my answer Diego

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a bit buggy on the latest 1.0.3 version, but I found a way to accomplish it, by doing :

```
postgresql: {
    adapter: require('sails-postgresql'),
    url: 'postgresql://postgres:blablabla@localhost:5432/simplerp',
    schemaName: 'radius',
}
```

On your config/datastores.js file.

Peace, out!